# Want to set true to boolean in WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, boolean

We are Creating a WSDL for soap request , where we have a boolean variable. As we know boolean is by default "false". But we need to have it as true.

I wanted to know where to set this value to true. So even if the variable is not set, it will take as True.
Please advice.

thanks in advance.

** More info: **

```
<complexType name="User">
<sequence>
 <element name="IMAddress" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
 <element name="**active**" type="xsd:boolean"/>
 <element name="address" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
```

so, i want my wsdl to have a variable active to be default true.
My WSDL is a "WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)"

```
    <!-- Create wsdl file -->
    <java classname="org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <classpath refid="axis-classpath" />
  <jvmarg value="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${env.log4j.configuration}"/>
        <arg value="--output" /> <arg value="${service}.wsdl" />
 </java>
```

i tried setting the active variable to be true in my User bean, but that did not help.

Comment: Hi, please provide your WSDL if you expect any help ;) In your WSDL change `default="false"` to `default="true"` ...

Comment: Thanks Gaël , i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsd:element name="isCaseSensitive" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>
```

Or set Annotation to the field in a class :

```
@XmlElement(defaultValue = "false")
private boolean isCaseSensitive;
```